# Creating backbone routes dynamically based on flags

Tags: backbone.js, routes

I am trying to create backbone routes for a user dynamically , only if the logged in user has the permission to view that particular route.In my current implementation i have created the routes and call the corresponding routing function and in that function i will check , if the user has the required privilege, if not rerouted to a default page. Can i create the routes itself based on the condition so that i don't have to check every time whether user has the appropriate privileges.

```
var Workspace = Backbone.Router.extend({
  routes: { 
    "help":                 "help",    
    "search/:query":        "search",  
    "search/:query/p:page": "search",
    "default":  "default"  
  },

  help: function() {
    if(!permission1){
      router.navigate('default', true);
    }
    //write logic
  },

  search: function(query, page) {
    if(!permission2){
      router.navigate('default', true);
    }
    //write logic
  },

 //write logic for other routes

});
```

Comment: You can asynchronously load a file with extra routes if user has permissions

Comment: can you please explain , i do not understand the answer.Thank you

Comment: I mean you can use module loaders like requirejs and do something like `if(permission){ require('module-with-extra-routes');};`

Comment: I will have to try it out to see if it will work or not, but for the present i have implemented it by manually creating routes using this.route() of backbone.js itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to the problem i came up with after reading the backbone js documentation is as follows:

```
var GlobalRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
initialize: function () {
    this.route('*path','default',showDefault);
    if (permission1) {
        this.route('menu1', 'menu1', showMenu1);
    }
    if (permission2) {
        this.route('menu2', 'menu2', renderMenu2);
    }
    if (permission3) {
        this.route('menu3', 'menu3', renderMenu3);
    }
}
});
```

Creating the routes likes this means that if a user does not have permission to view a certain route , there is no need for checking permission again as the routing will not happen as it is never created.

Comment: _"after reading the backbone documentation"_, that's a key point to finding solutions to development problems. Congratulations on doing that, succeeding and coming back to share your solution!